# How to run a container without a shell in GitLab CI job

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to run [conform](https://github.com/talos-systems/conform) as part of my pipeline to check commit messages, but the [container image](https://hub.docker.com/r/autonomy/conform) lacks a shell, and has entrypoint `/conform` and argument `enforce`. My `.gitlab-ci.yml` should look like:

```yaml
conform:
  image: docker.io/autonomy/conform:latest
```

without a script section, but as far as I know this is not allowed in GitLab.

### Edit

There is a GitLab [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/19717) open on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always install `conform` as part of your CI:

```yaml
conformJob:
  image: golang
  script:
    - go get github.com/talos-systems/conform
    - conform enforce
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: If it solved your problem then you could accept the answer:)